# Send inputdata from textbox automatically

Tags: jquery, html, css, json

Goal:
Every time you make a input data in the textbox (named txtInputData) you send the data to the server automatically and you compare the input data to the database's table.
In the end you retrieve a true or false if the data of txtInputData is the same from the database.

Problem:
I don't know how to make the textbox to send the data to the server with json automatically in every time when you make a input data.

I don't know where to start? It sounds to be more complicated than I thought.

Info:
*Jquery with Json is strongly recommended.

Comment: when you are changing input data - `input` field fires `onchange` event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="txtInputData"/>
```

you can do this:

```
$('#txtInputData').keyup(function(e){
    $.ajax({
        url:'/whatever',
        data: { text: this.value },
        success: function(data) {
            // if you need to do anything on return from server
        }
    });
});
```

onchange event generally only fires when you are leaving the text field, but using the keyup, you can send the data on every keystroke.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is just a basic starting point. You are talking about several blocks of code on both client and server side. I would insert a JS call function in the [input type="text" id="txtInpData" onkeydown="(chk_txtinp)"/>. This function would read the string in the text box on each keystroke and call an ajax/jason function to post it to the server along with a task code.
 This tells the server how to handle this incoming text. It is up to you if encryption is used. Completing all of this would take pages of code and real-time feedback just for error checking. 
Comparing 2 strings for equality sounds like the easy part. Your comparison should return 'true' or 'false' to a variable preset to null char ("") so the next thread of code knows a clear decision was made.

Comment: Thank you for your help!